# Facebook server-side OAuth 2.0 on localhost:8080 can't get access token missing redirect_uri

Tags: facebook, playframework-2.0, oauth-2.0, localhost, facebook-oauth

There are many other question related to this, but they didn't help me fix my problem.

I'm using the Facebook server-side login for a website, which I want to test locally. The path that initiates the login action is [http://localhost:8080/fblogin] (this redirects to the Facebook login dialogue, and goes from there).

I can successfully get the code, but when I try to exchange that for an access token, I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Missing redirect_uri parameter.","type":"OAuthException","code":191}}
```

I am providing the redirect_uri, url encoded and it is the same as the one I use to get the first code. Here is the url I'm using to request the access token (with the all-caps query string parameters replaced with their actual values, of course):

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffblogin&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=CODE_FROM_FB

I suspect this might have to do with how my app is set up on Facebook. Here are the values I have set:

```
Display Name: (an actual display name here) 
App Domains: localhost 
Contact email: (an actual email here) 
Site URL: [http://localhost:8080/fblogin]
```

What do I need to tweak in the settings to get this to work? Or does this look correct?

By the way, if it makes any difference, I am using the Play! framework, version 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a little more, I found that it was necessary for me to use POST when sending the request from my server to get the access token.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that using POST worked for you as this didn't for me.

In any case, did you add the query parameters using setQueryParameter()?  (see [How to make multiple http requests in play 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758956/how-to-make-multiple-http-requests-in-play-2/12768985#12768985))

Comment: Yeah, using setQueryParameter() was necessary to get it to work. What error message are you getting?